# Tasked with a very large email conversion project and lost

Tags: database, email, relational

Im not sure where to start or what to even consider using for the following problem.

I have a Lotus Notes infrastructure with many user mail files that I need extracted and stored into another format/database such as sql. After the conversion I need to find a way to index all of the emails, while maintaining, from, to, subject, and content, attachments are not important. I need some way to search for all emails containing a keyword or context, regardless of sender, and pulling them all in a displayable search form in order of date. Does anyone know what may help my situation?

Comment: What programming languages are you familiar with?

Answer (score 0):

software that does what you want is called [E-mail_archiving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_archiving), there are many products, and for example you could try an open source one, http://www.mailarchiva.com/index.do

If mailarchiva does not import natively nsf files, you just have to convert them to a format they support.

Comment: Enkive is; it can read files in Mbox format, and you can convert notes to Mbox using http://kevin.deldycke.com/2010/09/convert-lotus-notes-nsf-files-mbox-nlconverter/